# In mobile devices the site does not respond propertly but on desktop it works perfectly fine

Tags: html, css

I have this html code of my home page. The website is wwww.chatziefraimidis.com. It works perfectly fine in a desktop browser but in mobile the footer and the header are smaller than the screen and that even more weirdly happens only on the home page and on the other pages with exactly the same code it works both on desktop and mobile browser correctly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

and the coresponding css code is

```css
   body{
   font: 15px/1.5 "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   font-weight:normal;
   background: #f6f6f6;
}

/*Global*/
.container{
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

header ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.button_1{
  height:32px;
  background:#7B68EE;
  border: 0;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.dark{
  padding:15px;
  background:#35424a;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*Header**/
header{
  background: #35424a;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding-top:20px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom:    #7B68EE 5px solid;
}

header a{
  color:#f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

header #branding{
  float:left;
}

header #branding h1{
  margin:0;
}

header nav{
  float:right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a{
  color:#7B68EE;
  font-weight:normal;
}

header .current2 a{
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:normal;
}


header a:hover{
  color:#cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* showcase*/
#showcase{
  min-height:600px;
  min-width:500px;
  background:url('../img/showcase.png') no-repeat 0 -100px ;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#showcase h1{
  margin-top:100px;
  font-size:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: #35424a  ;
  opacity: 0.6;
}


  #showcase p{
    font-size:20px;
    background: #35424a ;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }

/*newsletter*/
  #newsletter{
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#35424a;
  }

  #newsletter h1{
    float:left;
   font-size:17px;
  }

  #newsletter form{
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
  }

  #newsletter input[type="email"]{
    padding:4px;
    height:25px;
    width: 250px;
  }

/*boxes*/
   #boxes{
     margin-top: 20px;
   }

   #boxes .box{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    width:33%;
    padding:10px;
   }

   #boxes .box img{
    width:30%;
   }

   /*side bar*/
  aside#sidebar{
  float:right;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px
  }
/*main cal*/

 article#main-col{
   float:left;
   width: 65%;
 }


/*projects*/
ul#services li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  boarder:#cccccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background:#e6e6e6;
}
div.gallery {

  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }

  .column {
    width: 49.9%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column {
     width: 100%;
   }

}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/*people*/
ul#people li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  boarder:#cccccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  float: left;
  background:#e6e6e6;
}
ul#people img{
  float: left;
}

/*form*/
aside#sidebar .quote input, aside#sidebar .quote textarea {
width:90%;
padding: 5px;
}

  /*footer*/
    footer{
      padding:20px;
      margin-top:20px;
      color:#ffffff;
      background-color:#483D8B;
    /* text-align: center;*/
    }

    .column1 {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      margin-left:50px;

    }

    .column2 {
      float; top;
      float: right;
      width: 50%;
      margin-right:50px;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  }

  .fa:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-linkedin {
    background: #007bb5;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-youtube {
    background: #bb0000;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
  }



  .fa-android {
    background: #a4c639;
    color: white;
  }


/*media quaeris*/
@media(max-width:768px){
 header #branding, header nav , header li , #newsletter h1, #newsletter form, #boxes .box,
 article#main-col, aside#sidebar
 {
   float:none;
   text-align:center;
    width:100%;
 }

 header {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 }

 #showcase{
 background-size:768px;
 }

#showcase h1{
  margin-top:40px;
}

#newsletter button, .quote button{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#newsletter form input[type="email"], .quote input, .quote textarea{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
         <div class="container">
              <div id="branding">
                <h1><span class="highlight">Fasma</span> Engineers</h1>
              </div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                  <li><a href="people.html">People</a></li>
                  <li class="current2"><a href="index.html">|EN</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index-GR.html">GR|</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
         </div>
    </header>

    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>World Class Structural And Geotechnical Engineers</h1>
        <p>Expienced With The Most Prestigious Projects</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id= "newsletter">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Subsctibe to our NewsLetter</h1>
        <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
          <button type="submit" class= "button_1">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: In the CSS max-width: 500px breakpoint I find a lot of calsses that are not provided in your HTMl code. The CSS wont work proberly if your classes youa dress there do not exist in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `min-width: 500px;` from *style.css line 90*.
and add

```
@media(min-width:500px){
  #showcase{
 min-width:500px;
 }
}
```

So It will look like -

[image: responsive layout on mobile]

Comment: Can you please tell me what is not working because I opened your website's home page in my phone it is working fine without any problem. It will be good to **share screenshot of your phone**.

Comment: Actually it took some hours to update the file from the server. Thank you  very much !

Answer (score 0):

Convert your widths to use percentages if you want a really responsive layout.

```
header {
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 }

 #showcase{
 background-size:88%;
 }

#showcase h1{
  margin-top:5%;
}
```